# HTML: Radio Button

Tags: html, radio-button

In the below code, user have to choose if he has car or not with radio button.
if "yes" radio button is set "car name" input field is enabled,
if "no" radio button is set "car name" input field is disabled
There is a "test" button, when it is clicked "yes" radio button is set, but the function associated with  "yes" radio button is not triggered.

---

can anyone please explain why the function associated with "yes" radio button is not triggered when "test" button is clicked?

---

Is there any way to achieve this? i,e when "test" button is clicked "yes" radio button should be set and this should trigger function enable_carname.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Radio Buttons</h2>

<form>
please choose:
<div>have car:</div> 
<input type="radio" name="car" id="no" value="no" onchange="disable_carname()" > no<br>
<input type="radio" name="car" id="yes" value="yes" onchange="enable_carname()"checked>yes<br>
carname:<input type="text" id="carname">
</form> 
<button onclick="set_yes_radio()">test</button>
</body>
<script>
function disable_carname()
{
 document.getElementById("carname").disabled=true;
}

function enable_carname()
{
 document.getElementById("carname").disabled=false;
}

function set_yes_radio()
{
 document.getElementById("yes").checked=true;
}
</script>
</html>
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it already works to me.

Comment: Oh, you mean enable carname when test is clicked.  You need some additional Javascript on the button to do that; the `onchange` only works when the user clicks on the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can anyone please explain why the function associated with "yes" radio button is not triggered when "test" button is clicked?

It's because you're not invoking `enable_carname()` function, that is - you're not actually changing the 'yes' button to checked. According to your setup, the solution would be:

```
function disable_carname() {
    document.getElementById("carname").disabled=true;
}

function enable_carname() {
    document.getElementById("carname").disabled=false;
}

function set_yes_radio() {
    document.getElementById("yes").checked=true;
    enable_carname(); //invoking the function which will actually enable 'carname' field
}
```

But, I'd argue that the whole approach you've tried here is quite confusing and it can only complicate your life. My solution is simply a patch to the proposed solution.

Maybe try to think about some default state. Let's say that 'no' button is checked by default and `carname` field is disabled. Instead of `test` button, that can be `submit`. I imagine that this is a part of a survey or something similar. If you'd like to try that different approach, give it a try and let me know if you need more help.

Btw, check [how to set attribute to DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) instead of hard-coding it in HTML. Of course, you can also remove it in similar fashion.

Side note: the text `carname` should be a `<label>` for the 'carname' input filed. [MDN: label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<h2>Radio Buttons</h2>

<form>
    please choose:
    <div>have car:</div>
    <input type="radio" name="car" id="no" value="no" onclick="disable_carname()"> no<br>
    <input type="radio" name="car" id="yes" value="yes" onclick="enable_carname()" checked>yes<br>
    carname:<input type="text" id="carname">
</form>
<button onclick="set_yes_radio()">test</button>
<script>
    function disable_carname() {
        document.getElementById("carname").disabled = true;
    }

    function enable_carname() {
        document.getElementById("carname").disabled = false;
    }

    function set_yes_radio() {
        document.getElementById("yes").checked = true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

set onclick as an attribute on your inout like this

```
<input type="radio" name="car" id="no" value="no" onclick="disable_carname()" > no<br>
```